# Query regarding status Temporary Residence card holder of Georgia

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, russia, georgia-country, ukraine

I am a India Passport holder with Temporary Residence card hold of Georgia.
So I would like to know if I want to visit Ukraine, Russia and Schengen countries then do I required VIsa for the entry into these countries?

Regards
Braj

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you require a visa for all of these countries. Depending on where you’re travelling to in Russia, you may be eligible for an e-visa.

https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b